# В чем проблема со Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Хочу преобразовать массив некоторых идентификаторов (все типа `int`) в список с некоторой попутной фильтрацией ( в список не нужно добавлять все идентификаторы).

Вот код:

```
ArrayList<Integer> visitorsIdexes = Arrays.stream(targetVisitors)
    .filter(id -> checkVisitor(id, target.getTargetSegmentCube()))
    .map(id -> Integer.valueOf(id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Только оне не компилируется с такой проблемой:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Collector<Object,?,List<Object>>` to `Supplier<R>`
> - The method `collect(Supplier<R>, ObjIntConsumer<R>, BiConsumer<R,R>)` in the type `IntStream` is not applicable for the arguments
>   `(Collector<Object,capture#1-of ?,List<Object>>)`

Что-то в полном ступоре, почему не работает..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы не преобразовали `IntStream` в `Stream<Integer>`. По факту `map(id -> Integer.valueOf(id))` ничего не делает, потому что `map` возвращает тот же `IntStream`. Чтобы преобразовать в объектный поток в общем случае нужен `mapToObj`, а в вашем конкретном проще всего написать `boxed()`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> visitorsIdexes = Arrays.stream(targetVisitors)
    .filter(id -> checkVisitor(id, target.getTargetSegmentCube()))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз нашел описание